# React .push is not a function

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I'm trying to make a to-do app.

First, I detect the change in the input and assign it to the state named todo.

`const [todo, setTodo] = useState("");`

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
  setTodo(e.target.value);
}
```

then i try to add the information in **todo** to the **todos state**, which is empty array when the button is clicked.

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]); 
    const handleClick = () => {
    setTodos(todos.push(todo));
    console.log(todos);
}[enter image description here][1]
```

At the first click, it adds as seen below.
However, on the second click I get the following error: **Uncaught TypeError: todos.push is not a function**

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CGgd.png)

The full code is as follows:

```
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState(""); 
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]); 

const handleChange = (e) => {
  setTodo(e.target.value);
}

const handleClick = () => {
    setTodos(todos.push(todo));
    console.log(todos);
}

return(
    <>
        <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
        <button onClick={handleClick}>add</button>
    </>
)
```

}

I'm wondering where i went wrong.

Comment: What do you think the push method returns? Also note you should never mutate values held in state.

Comment: you are setting your state array to become a number so it wont work the second time. `push` returns the lengh of the array https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the spread operator.

Also you state mutation won't update in time for the console log below to be fired, use a `useEffect()` and pass `todos` as the dependancy for it to watch for updates on and pass the console log into there.

```js
 const [todo, setTodo] = useState(""); 
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]); 

const handleChange = (e) => {
  setTodo(e.target.value);
}

const handleClick = () => {
    setTodos([...todos, todo]);
    // This will spread in the previous todos, then place todo within the array.

   setTodo('');
   // also, looking at your code, you probably need to empty todo afterwards.
}

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(todos);
}, [todos])

return(
    <>
        <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
        <button onClick={handleClick}>add</button>
    </>
)
```

Comment: dont use words like `spreeeeead opperraattoorrrrr `

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I will take into account what other guys have said.

Comment: No problem, the thing is, that `useState` although set to an array, does not contain any "array type" properties that you can use such as `.push()` as there's a lot of magic happening in the background of the `useState()` hook, to make updating viable etc 

Comment: No problem, React is a strange one. Although a super great framework, there are some layers of abstraction that can confuse new users, but thats what Stackoverflow is for and the lovely community of Developers. Keep grinding, you're on a good path, and remember... Rome wasn't built in a day 

Comment: Aside from your help, I want to hug you for your motivating words, my friend. It was something i needed nowadays.  I hope everything goes well in your life.

Comment: No problem, feel free to contact me via my email on my profile with anything you need, either a helping hand with code or not 